# How I can Convert T-SQL to Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, lambda

How I can do convert this query to Linq or Lambda Expression?

```
SELECT SURECTNM.RolId,
       IZIN_LIST.* 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Damga, SurecId FROM WEB_KULLANICISUREC
) IZIN_SUREC
LEFT JOIN WEB_SURECROL SURECTNM
    ON IZIN_SUREC.SurecId = SURECTNM.SurecID
LEFT JOIN WEB_KULLANICISUREC AS IZIN_LIST
    ON IZIN_SUREC.Damga = IZIN_LIST.Damga and SURECTNM.RolId = IZIN_LIST.RolId
WHERE IZIN_SUREC.Damga = '9EE15E44-C7B3-4AD5-A73F-3A2B4B49C0CC'
```

I'm using Database First.

WEB_KULLANICISUREC a entity classes,

The relationship between WEB_KULLANICISUREC and WEB_ROLSUREC  is provided by SurecID.

```
 public partial class WEB_KULLANICISUREC
{
    public int KullaniciSurecId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Damga { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SurecId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RolId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> OnayDurumu { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> SurecComplate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> SurecAktif { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> RedDurumu { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Tarih { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IDonaypersonel { get; set; }

    public virtual WEB_ROL WEB_ROL { get; set; }
    public virtual WEB_KULLANICI WEB_KULLANICI { get; set; }
    public virtual WEB_SURECTANIM WEB_SURECTANIM { get; set; }
}



  public partial class WEB_SURECROL
{
    public int SurecRolID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SurecID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RolId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> OnayDurumu { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> SurecTamam { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> SurecAktif { get; set; }
    public string surecrol_eposta { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> WEB_SURECROL_SURECTANIM_Guid { get; set; }

    public virtual WEB_ROL WEB_ROL { get; set; }
    public virtual WEB_SURECTANIM WEB_SURECTANIM { get; set; }
}
```

My Linq Expression:

```
var Surecim = Surecler.Select(s=> new  { s.SurecId , s.Damga}).Distinct().Join(
                db.WEB_SURECROL.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                SURECDAMGALAR => SURECDAMGALAR.SurecId,
                SURECROLLER => SURECROLLER.SurecID,
                (SURECDAMGALAR, SURECROLLER) => new { SURECDAMGALAR, SURECROLLER }).Join(Surecler,
                surecTanim => new { surecTanim.SURECDAMGALAR.Damga,surecTanim.SURECROLLER.RolId  },
                SUREC_LIST => new { SUREC_LIST.Damga,SUREC_LIST.RolId  },
                (surecTanim,SUREC_LIST) => new {surecTanim,SUREC_LIST }
                ).Select(x=> new {
                    x.surecTanim.SURECROLLER.WEB_SURECTANIM.SurecAdi,
                    x.surecTanim.SURECROLLER.WEB_SURECTANIM.SurecTip,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.Damga,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.OnayDurumu,
                    x.surecTanim.SURECROLLER.WEB_ROL.RolAdi,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.SurecComplate,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.SurecAktif,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.RedDurumu,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.Aciklama,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.WEB_KULLANICI.GirisAdi,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.Tarih,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.IDonaypersonel,

                });
```

Lambda generating this T-SQL Query;

the problem is; Because it uses Inner join, it does not return all values ​​in the table.

```
{SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent4].[SurecAdi] AS [SurecAdi], 
[Extent4].[SurecTip] AS [SurecTip], 
[Extent3].[Damga] AS [Damga], 
[Extent3].[OnayDurumu] AS [OnayDurumu], 
[Extent5].[RolAdi] AS [RolAdi], 
[Extent3].[SurecComplate] AS [SurecComplate], 
[Extent3].[SurecAktif] AS [SurecAktif], 
[Extent3].[RedDurumu] AS [RedDurumu], 
[Extent3].[Aciklama] AS [Aciklama], 
[Extent6].[GirisAdi] AS [GirisAdi], 
[Extent3].[Tarih] AS [Tarih], 
[Extent3].[IDonaypersonel] AS [IDonaypersonel]
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent1].[Damga] AS [Damga], 
    [Extent1].[SurecId] AS [SurecId]
    FROM [dbo].[WEB_KULLANICISUREC] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Damga] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Distinct1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[SurecID] AS [SurecID], [Extent2].[RolId] AS [RolId]
    FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WEB_SURECROL] AS [Extent2] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join1] ON ([Distinct1].[SurecId] = [Join1].[SurecID]) OR (([Distinct1].[SurecId] IS NULL) AND ([Join1].[SurecID] IS NULL))
INNER JOIN [dbo].[WEB_KULLANICISUREC] AS [Extent3] ON (([Distinct1].[Damga] = [Extent3].[Damga]) OR (([Distinct1].[Damga] IS NULL) AND ([Extent3].[Damga] IS NULL))) AND (([Join1].[RolId] = [Extent3].[RolId]) OR (([Join1].[RolId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent3].[RolId] IS NULL)))
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WEB_SURECTANIM] AS [Extent4] ON [Join1].[SurecID] = [Extent4].[SurecId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WEB_ROL] AS [Extent5] ON [Join1].[RolId] = [Extent5].[RolId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WEB_KULLANICI] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent3].[IDonaypersonel] = [Extent6].[KullaniciId]
WHERE [Extent3].[Damga] = @p__linq__1}
```

How do I get him to use LeftJoin?

Comment: Are you using Entity or SQLClient class?  The solution is different depeneding on your connection to the database.

Comment: I'm using Entity, this T-SQL is solved my problem but I'm tried convert to lambda, 
unfortunately I did not succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
surecModel = Surecler.Select(s=> new  { s.SurecId , s.Damga})
                .Distinct()
                //
                .Join(
                db.WEB_SURECROL.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                SURECDAMGALAR => SURECDAMGALAR.SurecId,
                SURECROLLER => SURECROLLER.SurecID,
                (SURECDAMGALAR, SURECROLLER) => new { SURECDAMGALAR, SURECROLLER })
                //
                .GroupJoin(Surecler.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                surecTanim => new { surecTanim.SURECDAMGALAR.Damga,surecTanim.SURECROLLER.RolId  },
                SUREC_LIST => new { SUREC_LIST.Damga,SUREC_LIST.RolId  },
                (surecTanim,SUREC_LIST) => new {surecTanim,SUREC_LIST }
                )
                //
                .Select(x=> new {
                    x.surecTanim.SURECROLLER.WEB_SURECTANIM.SurecAdi,
                    x.surecTanim.SURECROLLER.WEB_SURECTANIM.SurecTip,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().Damga,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().OnayDurumu,
                    x.surecTanim.SURECROLLER.WEB_ROL.RolAdi,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().SurecComplate,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().SurecAktif,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().RedDurumu,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().Aciklama,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().WEB_KULLANICI.GirisAdi,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().Tarih,
                    x.SUREC_LIST.FirstOrDefault().IDonaypersonel,

                });
```

Solved...

I would like to use it if you have different suggestion.